# How to center TopNavigation - Master Pages

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, custom-masterpage

I am working on a project and one of my tasks is to create custom master page. I have a master page in place already - Thanks to me!
One question: How do I center align Top Navigation?

Many thanks,
Sep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a custom master page and specify the style ( center alignment) to the div tag that is holding your `TopNavContainer`. I have used table structure and when I assign `align="center"` for `<tr>` tag that was holding `<Sharepoint:AspMenu.../>` tag.